# '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'writerow'

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to replace characters in a CSV but I am getting an error.

```
data = csv.reader(open('hashes.csv', 'r'),  quotechar='|')
    writer = csv.reader(open('hashesCor.csv', 'w'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

for line in data:
    line=str(line)
    new_line = str.replace(line, '|', "','") 
    writer.writerow(new_line)
```

> writer.writerow(new_line) AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no
>   attribute 'writerow'

I have another part of the code that does `writerow` on text file and it works, but not on CSV in `csv.reader`. Also, if anyone have a better idea on how to replace characters in CSV, You are more than welcome.
I am using `python 3.6.3`

Comment: `writer = csv.writer` not `csv.reader`

Comment: Read your error message: You made a `csv.reader`. Can you imagine why you're not allowed to write to it?

Comment: My god. Thanks. I guess i need a vacation...

Answer (score 2):

It's because you should use `csv.writer` instead, since you want to write.